# What optimizations does the compiler perform by using template metaprogramming technique that can outperform runtime code?

Tags: c++, templates

I have been recently introduced to the topic of template metaprogramming in C++, of course I wanted to get my hands dirty with it and I wrote some code to play with:

`

```
template<uint64_t N>
struct fibonacci {
    static constexpr uint32_t value = fibonacci<N - 1>::value + fibonacci<N - 2>::value;
};
template<>
struct fibonacci<0> {
    static constexpr uint32_t value = 1;
};
template<>
struct fibonacci<1> {
    static constexpr uint32_t value = 1;
};

uint64_t fib(uint64_t n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;

    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}


int main()
{
    constexpr uint64_t fibValue = 40;
    cout << "start functional fib:" << endl;
    cout << fib(fibValue) << endl;
    cout << "finished functional fib" << endl;
    cout << "start templated fib: " << endl;
    cout << fibonacci<fibValue>::value << endl;
    cout << "finish templated fib" << endl;
}
```

`

The code implements the famous Fibonacci function in two ways - one using template and the other using recursion. What I don't understand is how the compiler does its work so fast before the programm executes. It uses the same recursive logic but somehow it seems that the time of *fibonacci::value* being calculated is not affected by *fibValue*, so inputs like 200 are ok, while *fib(40)* already takes time and for bigger values it gets stuck completely.

My question is - How does the compiler outperforms the regular recursive implementation of the fibonnaci function?

there is other implementation of the Fibonacci function:

`

```
uint64_t fibFast(uint16_t n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;

    uint64_t* cache = new uint64_t[n + 1];
    cache[0] = cache[1] = 1;

    for (uint16_t i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        cache[i] = cache[i - 1] + cache[i - 2];

    return cache[n];
}
```

`

This implementation is calculating the value of fib(n) roughly at the same time but at runtime and it uses O(n) additional memory space. Does it mean the compiler uses the last version of the code or is there any other trick here.

I have seen that there were similar discussions about the topic but I didn't find the explanation of what happens internally and why is it happening.

Comment: The point of this is that the metaprogramming calculation in the first case is not done at runtime at all. So it doesn't take any time at runtime. Everything is done at compile time. However, such techniques are mostly obsolete now with later C++ versions. Assuming you properly `delete`ed your memory you could just add some `constexpr`/`consteval` and have the same effect in C++20 and later for example. And if you hadn't used a cache (it is an unnecessary complication) you could achieve the same with `constexpr` functions since C++14 easily and C++11 with some care.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. If you are asking whether the compiler internally caches the individual sub results of the template metaprogramming approach similar to how your second approach does it (even if the array isn't required and two single variables would do), then yes, the compiler is allowed, and is likely going to, cache template instantiations. It would be pointless to repeat the calculation of a `constexpr` variable.

Comment: @user17732522 Note, though, that OP's second approach (or third) isn't actually caching the results for memoization porpuses, but just for ease of calculation.

Comment: Yes, the question what about the compiler pre-execution policy. I did forget to mention the other way with two variables but, the point was actually to differ between the first case (the template) and the second case (recursive function) that from the first glance use the same recursion logic but achieve different results.

Comment: You can improve the performance of the recursive approach using memoization: https://godbolt.org/z/f3PTWYE61

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite clear some details of your question, but the following observation can be made relying on typical compiler behavior, which likely explains your observations.

Consider a call to `fib(6)`. If you work out what happens when this call is made you will make the following conclusions. `fib(6)` ends up:

1. Calling `fib(5)`.
2. Calling `fib(4)`.

Now, what happens during the call to `fib(5)`? `fib(5)` ends up:

3. Calling `fib(4)`.
4. Calling `fib(3)`.

Your attention is drawn to the fact that two calls to `fib(4)` get made. Each call to `fib(4)` requires full execution of all recursive calls that results from that. That your first clue. You were likely expecting that `fib(4)` gets called once, during this quest. Nope.

You will find, as you map out the full sequence of calls to moderate values of `n` is that they multiply like rabbits. Very, very quickly. If you work out on paper and pencil how many times `fib(2)` gets called, as a result of calling `fib(6)` you might be surprised at the results. At `fib(2)` gets called even more times as a result of `fib(10)`. At runtime, a lot of wheels get spun in place, before they come to a full stop. And there is no obvious optimization path here. The Golden Rule Of Computer Programming is fully in force here: "Your computer always does exactly what you tell it to do, instead of what you want it to do".

On the flip side of the coin: each instance of the `fibonacci` template is a discrete class. C++ compilers are very good at dealing with a large number of classes. They are good at efficiently keeping track of them.

Subsequently, once a C++ compiler instantiates `fibonacci<4>`, which includes `fibonacci<4>::value`, it ***does not need to go through the work of instantiating it again*** the next time it needs to evaluate what `fibonacci<4>::value` is. The class already exists. The compiler simply looks it up.

So, for all values of `n` that come up during compilation the C++ compiler will compute `fibonacci<n>::value` exactly once. On the other hand, at runtime, `fib(n)` ends up getting called umpteen times.